# Two css hovering effects in one, how two effects are linked with each other?

Tags: html, css

How to make two css code linked with each other?

For example:

An icon which is flipping when hovering it but it is also slightly going up with its white background.

You can see in this website https://www.designhenge.com, on its home page services section. How both css are interconnected with each other? What is the code behind it?

I have already made the icon flipping hovering effect. But I don't know how the white background box is slightly going up along with flipping icon on it.

These are the elements in the `designhenge` website which have flipping icons with white background box going up with them when hovering it:

[image: designhenge site]

Answer (score 0):

you have to use **transform:translate** property on the **div  hover** section, they have used the code to do that

```
.info-card:hover {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-15px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-15px);
    transform: translateY(-15px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this below css:

```
.info-card:hover {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-15px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-15px);
    transform: translateY(-15px);
}
```

You can also check like this:

[image]